# Injectivity of fourier coefficient map

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am asking about the proof of corollary 2.0.2 in this: 
http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/05b_banach_fourier.pdf

I understand most of the proof, but I don't understand how they proved injectivity.

They define $Tf = \{\hat{f}(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \in c_0$.

They conclude $T$ is injective because of the density of finite Fourier series in $C^0$ and density of $C^0$ in $L^1$. I don't understand how this follows at all! If someone could tell me which results they've used to conclude this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So the general principle is that $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the torus, and the isometric isomorphism is

$$f \mapsto \{\hat{f}(n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}.$$
So, an $L^2$ function is wholly determined by its fourier coefficients. If all the fourier coefficients of $f$ are zero, then since the identification is an isomorphism, $\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}=0$!

The isometry is encapsulated in Parseval's identity:

$$\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}^2 = \sum_n |\hat{f}(n)|^2.$$

Comment: If the spaces are isometrically isomorphic, doesn't that imply that $T$ is surjective? Which it isn't?

Comment: Why do you not think it's surjective? Edit: I see, you have defined $T$ as mapping into $c_0$. So, $T$ is actually surjective onto $\ell^2$, a subspace of $c_0$.